# How to Add Iframe Current Domain on Visiting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dns, redirect, http-redirect

Listen this is main site link >>> `http://magazinerpros.blogspot.com/`

Now i want that if someone click on the above link. then it should open to hold another link too. like you see in Example #2. that hold extra frame link { `http://www.inframe.com/p/preview.html?` } before the main link.

**Example #2**
http://www.iframe.com/p/preview.html?url=http://www.inframe.com

I tried to add script on my testing site, but it continuously loading when visit it.

Script that i added in the below site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.replace("http://www.iframe.com/p/preview.html?url=http://redirectssite.blogspot.com/");
</script>
```

http://www.inframe.com.

So please give me only javascript or jequery script. To make this redirection possible. which you see in **example #2**. So what script should i add in the site. so that after visiting it holds that another frame link before it in addressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are creating a redirect loop.

Either check the URL, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location !== "http://redirectssite.blogspot.com/") {
    window.location.replace("http://www.iframe.com/p/preview.html?url=http://redirectssite.blogspot.com/");
}
</script>
```

From the below script, it would work work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( !(window.location !== window.parent.location) ) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.inframe.com/p/preview.html?url=http://redirectssite.blogspot.com/");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks bundles bundles @bobdye,  the second one worked for me... I add the first script here but not worked its overloading. http://redirectssite.blogspot.com/ but when i add the second script in my another testing site. it worked greatly. http://testingsites2.blogspot.com/  again i would you you are the best, i was searching for the issue but no one was there to help me. but you resolve my issue. thanks billions to you. may you live long.